# Can't move file after download and unzip

Tags: r, encoding

I'm trying to download a zip file from a source, unzip it and after move to another directory.

First the download:

```
if (!file.exists("inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo")) {
  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
  download.file("ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_do_Universo/Agregados_por_Setores_Censitarios/SP_Capital_20180416.zip", tmp, quiet = TRUE)
  unzip(tmp, exdir = "inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo", junkpaths=T)
  unlink(tmp)
}
```

The file i want is on this directory `inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/SP Capital/Base informa�oes setores2010 universo SP_Capital (codificação inválida)/CSV/`, so when i try copy to `inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/` i get an error

```
file.rename("inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/SP%20Capital/Base%20informa%87oes%20setores2010%20universo%20SP_Capital(condificação inválida)/CSV/Domicilio02_SP1.csv",
            "inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/Domicilio02_SP1.csv")

Warning message:
In file.rename("inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/SP%20Capital/Base%20informa%87oes%20setores2010%20universo%20SP_Capital(condificação inválida)/CSV/Domicilio02_SP1.csv",  :      
it was not possible to rename file 'inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/SP%20Capital/Base%20informa%87oes%20setores2010%20universo%20SP_Capital(condificação inválida)/CSV/Domicilio02_SP1.csv'
for 'inst/extdata/sp_resultados_universo/Domicilio02_SP1.csv',
reason 'File or directory not found'
```

I'm translating the error message, so it could be inconsistent with english message.

I can change the directory name or move the file manually, but breaks the flow and it's not nice for reproducibility. How can i handle it inside R?

My system info:

```
Sys.info()
                                     sysname 
                                     "Linux" 
                                     release 
                             "4.9.0-6-amd64" 
                                     version 
"#1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07)" 
                                     machine 
                                    "x86_64"
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you on windows or linux? you may be having trouble with spaces and non-printables in your directories; you may also try to use the system() commands, where you put what you would write in bash or cmd-line inside the system() function

Comment: Thanks, Elio. I'm in Debian 9. I will edit the question include this. How could i use system function in this case?

Comment: If you use `system` or `system2`, make sure to read up on `shQuote`.

Answer (score 0):

when using R you can interact with the linux shell (or the windows cmd line) through a call to system() where you put the quoted command just as you would use in the shell,
for instance:

```
system("pwd") # prints current working directory
system("date") # prints 
system("ls | grep .R")  # prints a list of r scripts in the current working directory
system("mv file.txt /home/new_directory/file.txt") # moves your file to another directory
```